# How to include standard jdk library in emacs semantic?

Tags: java, emacs, emacs-semantic

I'm using Emacs 23.2. Here's how I'm loading semantic:

```
(setq semantic-default-submodes '(global-semantic-idle-scheduler-mode
                  global-semanticdb-minor-mode
                  global-semantic-idle-summary-mode
                  global-semantic-mru-bookmark-mode))
(semantic-mode 1)
```

So, if I create a simple java file and visit it, I get code completion for locally defined methods and classes. But I can't figure out how to make semantic aware of jdk libraries. For example, if I try `semantic-ia-complete-symbol` on a String variable, I get `Cannot find types for 'String blah'`.

Does anyone know how to load the jdk libraries into semanticdb so code completion of standard object types like String are available?

Answer (score 3):

Starting with CEDET 1.1, Semantic has support for retrieving class information through javap. You need to setup `cedet-java-jdk-root` variable to JAVA_HOME, and populate `semanticdb-javap-classpath` variable with list of paths to Java's system jars, like `rt.jar`, etc.

There is [an article](http://my-clojure.blogspot.de/2012/05/cedet-11-emacs-java.html) (in Russian, but you can get [translation](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http://my-clojure.blogspot.de/2012/05/cedet-11-emacs-java.html)) about setting Semantic up for Java completion - please look there for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you unzip src.zip that is found in $JAVA_HOME you can add a hook for you java mode like this:

```
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook
  '(lambda ()
     (semantic-add-system-include (getenv "JAVA_HOME") 'java-mode)))
```

It solves the problem for me with Emacs 23.3 and CEDET 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried CEDET in a while, so I'll blindly ask a few questions that might give insight into your problem.

1. I assume JDK is on your path, and Emacs can find it?
2. Since JDK is basically a bunch of jar files without source code, can Semantic parse that? Example: if you make your own `Class1.java`, compile it to `Class1.class` and then delete `Class1.java`, when you write `Class2.java` and reference some methods from `Class1`, can Semantic find them?
3. Have you tried [JDEE](http://jdee.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: Yes, jdk is on my path. I found src.jar inside the os x jdk and even tried extracting and visiting String.java. It seems semantic parses String.java into semanticdb, but when I'm back inside my custom java project, it can't seem to find methods for Strings. I've looked at JDEE, but my goal here is to understand semantic first before adding more complexity. I think it's mostly my ignorance of how semantic works, so I'll keep digging, but thanks for your response!